# maven how to automaticaly apply plugin from another artifact to project

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-plugin, maven-bom

I have to setup many maven projects having almost the same structure, same dependencies and same plugins.

So i decided to create a bom containing all my common dependencies. So my all other projects include this bom (by inheritance or import).

I want to do the same thing with maven plugins.
So I declare my plugins in `<plugins>` bloc in my bom project. Is there a better way to do that ?

What is the recommended way to externalize maven plugin configuration ?

Comment: A bom should be used as a dependency (meaning using in dependencyManagement) not by inhertiance. You can use a parent pom where you define all your plugins via pluginManagement....

Comment: @khmarbaise I can use my bom as parent project or import it via dependencyManagment like you say. But the purpose of my question is externalization of my plugins config. In other words, what is the best way to externalize plugin so that i can reuse them in one or many projets ?

Comment: Using a bom as parent is most of the time not so good idea. Better import it in dependencyMangement in your project. The configuration of plugins should be done in a separate project which you use as a parent... by going that way you can reuse that in any project...

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent POM with the plugin configuration and inherit it in your projects.

Importing BOMs does not work for your use case.

Comment: why importing bom does not work in my use case ?

Comment: Only `<dependencyManagement>` is imported from a BOM, all other parts are ignored.

Comment: I guess I can use  <pluginManagement> instead of  <dependencyManagement>

Comment: Actually, I am not completely sure if this works with `<pluginManagement>`. But `<pluginManagement>` does not add plugins to your build, it just fixes versions and configuration.